# Error occurred while loading a pre-trained model of h5 format

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, face-recognition, facenet

I have a problem loading a pre-trained model written as an .h5 file in my TensorFlow-GPU environment. ([LINK](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1pwQ3H4aJ8a6yyJHZkTwtjcL4wYWQb7bn) to the model associated as its weights)

To begin, I loaded this very model by means of **keras.models.load_model()**. An error popped up as illustrated in the following figure.
[image]

Then I used **tensorflow.keras.models.load_model()** instead. Still, I had the same problem, failing to load this model to my program.
[image]

Environment:

- TensorFlow-GPU: version 2.3.1
- Keras: version 2.4.3
- Python: version 3.8.5
- IDE: Visual Studio 2019

Any idea would be appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: remove line 7 and try again. Don't mix old keras with new keras. And still, it occurs try this in another environment eg colab/kaggle. If still exist, I think then there is something wrong with your h5 file.

Comment: I removed "import keras" and used tf.keras.models.load_model() to load it instead. But still, the same error showed up.

Comment: Is it possibly because I ran this code using a GPU instead of a CPU?

Comment: Hi, @M.Innat. I resolved the problem by re-creating another virtual environment (tensorflow-gpu 2.3.0). And still, I used keras.models.load_model(). To my surprise, it finally loaded this pre-trained model successfully. Thank you for the comment!